# Is $\limsup x_n = a \iff \limsup |x_n - a |= 0$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

We know that $\lim x_n = a$ is equivalent to $\lim |x_n-a|=0$.

I am trying to show that $$\limsup x_n = a \iff \limsup |x_n - a |= 0$$

Define $s_n := \sup_{m \geq n} x_m$. By definition, $\limsup x_n = \lim s_n$. So
$$\limsup x_n = a \iff \lim s_n = a \iff \lim |s_n - a|=0$$
Note that:  $s_n - a = \sup_{m \geq n} x_m - a = \sup_{m \geq n} \{x_m - a\}=: \bar s_n$. So:
$$\limsup x_n = a \iff \lim |\bar s_n|=0 $$

Moreover, defining $\tilde s_n := \sup_{m \geq n} |x_m - a|$
$$\limsup |x_n - a |= 0 \iff \lim \tilde s_n  = 0$$

It remains to show that
$$\lim |\bar s_n|=0 \iff \lim \tilde s_n  = 0 $$

But I think that it is not true. Do you have a counterexample?  or... is this true?

Comment: $\limsup (x_n-a)=0$ is correct. $\limsup |x_n-a| = 0$ is wrong by some distance. In fact, $\limsup |x_n - a| = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim x_n = a$.

Comment: Same goes for $\liminf (x_n-a)=0$ and $\liminf |x_n-a|=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False. Counter-example: $x_n=(-1)^{n}, a=1$.

Answer (score 2):

For a counter example, see the other answer. I am writting this answer to give just some explanations that does not fit into a comment in my opinion.

$\lim \sup |x_n-a|=0$ is in fact equivalent to $\lim x_n = a$.

Forward implication is given by: $ 0 \le |x_n-a| \le \sup_{m \ge n} |x_m-a| \to 0$, hence convergence by the squeeze theorem. (And the converse is trivial from the definition of $\lim \sup$).

Answer (score 2):

As geetha290km said in their answer, the claim is false and any piece-wise function is a proof of this. However, I have a feel that the statement without the absolute value bars (below) holds:
$$\limsup x_n=a \iff \limsup (x_n-a)=0$$
Because for other members $x_{n^*}$ (e.g. for $n$-s, for which $x_{n^*}=\liminf x_n=b$, it holds:
$$x_{n^*}-a=b-a<0=\limsup (x_n-a)$$